# SELECT: Which runs faster?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Employees are going to read data (a whole row) from the server through a website.

The data to be read by them, the rows, is the result of quite a few joins involving something more than 10 tables.

**Question:**

**1.** Should I create and refresh a new table containing the end-resulta data to be read so at presentation layer we just do Select top 1 from table?

**2.** Or should I execute a Select... and a large series of joins, multiplication, etc in order to get that one row?

---

I'm about to start with this and the first idea I have to admint was to build a big new table with the data, but this question popped up since I'm being carefull with normalization through tables, and building the new one would result in redundancy of data.

Have to say that the desired product is for the Employees webpage to access the data as fast as possible (this is why at first I thought about creating and refreshing a new table)

Thanks.

---

**EDIT**

about 300 (maybe 1k in the future) people is going to access the website. They will query this one row, do what they have to do with it and then hit OK so they get a new row (guess it will be 2 minutes between query and query). What we don't want to happen is: Employees are gonna get coached all the time, and one of those coaching factors is the time they take to work on a row (client I must say). So, if the query takes too long (a matter of seconds between every refresh would be "too long" for them) then I'd have to build a new way to take this into consideration. And of course I'd prefer not to.

---

**EDIT 2**

Once they hit OK, another query triggers to update data in the DataBase, then the original query so another row is sent to the webpage.

Comment: I guess that depends..

 - How many people will enter the site ? 
   
 - Is performance critic ?

   
   

 - Each table will got a lot of info (suggest to create index) or just a
   few    rows ?

   
   

 - Are you gonna use the info in the future for other stuff ? (which could mean that if you don't normalize, you could get repeated
      info)

You should consider some things before decided (or provide us more info)

Comment: It sounds like what you're trying to build is an indexed view.  Which SQL Server supports.

Comment: @MikeChristensen you want to suggest an indexed view for 10+ tables? Are you aware of all the limitations that prevent an indexed view from being possible, and the costs involved with maintaining such a view even if it is possible? This is not a magic bullet that will hand-wave performance pixie dust over a solution. :-)

Comment: Are they retrieving the row to actually edit it?

Comment: @AaronBertrand yes, they select and once they hit OK, another query triggers to update data, then they get another row.

Comment: And are you experiencing performance problems in locking a single row, or are you prematurely optimizing for a performance problem that doesn't yet exist? Are they really updating all 10+ tables that are involved in the join, or only certain columns from certain tables?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I've never written an indexed view in SQL Server.  I *have* written a materialized view in Oracle (same thing) and it was one of the most frustrating experiences I've ever encountered in a DB.  Hopefully, SQL Server's implementation is at least a little more straight forward.

Comment: @AaronBertrand prematurely optimizing I should say. Trying to make its foundations strong so not a lot of changes happen in the near future. No, not a lot of columns are going to be updated. Just a few.

Comment: I think you are taking a very "chicken little" approach here. Selecting a single row from a well-indexed table, updating it and then moving on to the next should be a fairly efficient operation no matter how much data you have.

Comment: @MikeChristensen please review the requirements and other considerations here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx Like I said, this isn't hand-wavy magic.

Comment: @MikeChristensen Actually you should view this topic on indexed views, as it gives a much more accurate picture of how restrictive they are: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432(v=sql.105).aspx The 2012 version is erroneously missing a *lot* of restrictions. I filed a documentation bug here: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/755360/doc-indexed-views-topic-does-not-list-complete-set-of-restrictions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Have to say that the desired product is for the Employees webpage to access the data as fast as possible

Why does it have to be as fast as possible? If it runs in 0.1 seconds, isn't that fast enough?

Is it because you are running the query in a loop? If so, then I suggest that you change your strategy to fetch data in bulk rather than one row at a time.

If you really do need it to be as fast as possible for whatever reason, then yes, having a precalculated result ready will be faster than making the query from the original data sources. Populating a table is one way of achieving this. Another way is to use a caching mechanism so that the request is only slow the first time, but repeated requests for the same data will be faster.

Note that either precalculating the results or using caching will increase performance, but may give you problems with stale data when the original data changes.

Comment: about 300 (maybe 1k in the future) people is going to access the website. They will query this one row, do what they have to do with it  and then hit OK so they get a new row (guess it will be 2 minutes between query and query). What we don't want to happen is: Employees are gonna get coached all the time, and one of those coaching factors is the time they take to work on a row (client I must say). So, if the query takes too long (a matter of seconds between every refresh would be "too long" for them) then I'd have to build a new way to take this into consideration.

Comment: will add this info to the question, think it can help.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with regular view first, and only if I have performance issues, I'll materialize it (either indexed view or manually create a new table and populate it with data).

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to have a normalized database and run a *potentially* more expensive query than have de-normalized data and a quicker query.  The second scenario I think could run into maintenance / readability issues not only for making sure your cache table is up-to-date, but all logic central to that data will have to be written to account for these scenarios.

If it gets accessed a lot, you may want to implement caching on the client retrieving this data (asp.net?) to prevent unnecessary calls.

Comment: didn't think about caching on client (yes .net).